# Modifying Devise's form_for to make Paperclip work?

Tags: devise, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a bit confused.

This is the `form_for` in the Getting Started section of Paperclip's Github repository:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
```

This is the `form_for` that is generated with Devise:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

How should I modify it to get Paperclip working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `:multipart => true` to the :html parameter like so.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true  }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Ahhh, finally solved after a week of trying to figure this out. Also, be sure to restart your server just in case. This helped me a lot, thanks!